# zsh expansion to create file name based on the directory name

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to use pandoc to compile all .markdown files in a directory into one pdf with the name of the pdf being the directory name plus a space and `notes.pdf`. I can compile all the markdown files into one pdf if I hardcode the pdf name but when I try and generate the pdf name, it fails.

For example, if I am in a directory with a file path called `path/to/markdown files`, I want to compile into a pdf called `markdown files notes.pdf`.

I have tried the following:

```
pandoc *.markdown -o $PWD notes.pdf
```

Error - "Pandoc can convert to PDF, but not from PDF."

```
pandoc *.markdown -o ${PWD notes.pdf}
```

Error - "bad substitution"

```
pandoc *.markdown -o '$PWD notes.pdf'
```

produces a pdf called $PWD(:t) notes.pdf

```
pandoc *.markdown -o $PWD" notes.pdf"
```

Error = "no matches found"

Does anyone know how I can get this working?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean e.g. that if the current working directory is `/home/pdoak/projects/wibble`, then you want the output file name to be `wibblenotes.pdf`?

Comment: Yes, but in your example I want a space between wibble and "notes.pdf" so that the filename would be "wibble notes.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$PWD:t` expands to the base name of the current directory. This needs to be unquoted or double-quoted, not single-quoted, because single quotes prevent expansion. The space needs to be quoted too since it is part of the file name.

```
pandoc -o "$PWD:t notes.pdf" *.markdown
```

Note that this uses zsh syntax. If you need that in plain sh (e.g. for a makefile), you can use

```
pandoc -o "${PWD##*/} notes.pdf" *.markdown
```

(In a makefile, double the `$`.)